How to know if f(a) is a local extremum using concavity
Let's suppose $f$ is differentiable twice.
How to know if $f(a)$ is a local extremum?
I know that when $f'(a)=0$ and $f'$ changes sign on $a$, then f(a) is a local extremum. But I have seen that you can find out it's a local extremum using concavity and $f''(a)$.
So how do we do that? And why does it work?
I mean the first method is very obvious that it's true (just by visualization) but the second method I really don't even understand it.

Loosely speaking, since second derivative is the slope of the first derivative, (consider local max) if $f$ has turning point at $x=a$ and $f''(a)<0$, this means the slope will of $f$ is decreasing in the neighbourhood at $a$, so the left-neightbourhood of $a$ will have positive slope and the right-neighbourhood of $a4 will have negative slope, which reduce to the first derivative argument. The local min side works similarly.

If $f'(a)=0$ and the sign $f''(x)$ doesn't change in a neighbourhood of $a$ means that in such neighbourhood the concavity, just by visualization, give you the information about the $\cup$ or $\cap$ shape of the graph of $f$ where the extreme point is $(a,f(a))$. That shape can suggest if there is a local maximum or minimum in $x=a$.
